# MapSqlParameterSource Does Not Map Properly with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for a stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

I am trying to call a stored procedure using mapped parameters with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` (Spring 3.0), but for some strange reason certain values do not get passed to the stored procedure (Oracle 11.2)!

The interface of the stored procedure in question:

```
PROCEDURE my_stored_proc(
  h_id IN NUMBER,
  h_type IN VARCHAR2,
  h_status in varchar2  DEFAULT null,
  h_end_date IN DATE DEFAULT null,
  h_reason IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT null,
  h_rating IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT null,
  h_position IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT null,
  h_rater_id IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT null,
  h_start_date IN DATE DEFAULT null,
  h_rater IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT null,
  h_supervisor IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT null,
  h_grade IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT null)
```

I only need to pass a small subset of parameters for the purpose of my functionality (not all):

```
String sql = "{call my_stored_proc(:h_id,:h_type,:h_reason,:h_position)}";

MapSqlParameterSource sqlParamMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
sqlParamMap.addValue("h_id", myObj.getHId(), Types.NUMERIC);
sqlParamMap.addValue("h_type", myObj.getHType(), Types.VARCHAR);
sqlParamMap.addValue("h_reason", myObj.getHReason(), Types.VARCHAR);
sqlParamMap.addValue("h_position", myObj.getHPosition(), Types.VARCHAR);

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
template.execute(sql, sqlParamMap, new PreparedStatementCallback<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps)
            throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        return ps.execute();
    }
);
```

As you can see, I am not utilizing all the stored procedure's parameters -- only the required and needed based on this particular functionality. Nonetheless, when I let `my_stored_proc()` to simply write the values of the parameters to a table, `h_reason` and `h_position` are empty even though during debugging `myObj.getHReason()` and `myObj.getHPosition()` both have proper values.

If I execute the stored procedure via the following anonymous block from SQL:

```
DECLARE
  h_id NUMBER;
  h_type VARCHAR2(200);
  h_reason VARCHAR2(200);
  h_position VARCHAR2(200);
begin
  h_id := 12352;
  h_type := 'Z';
  h_reason := 'L';
  h_position := 'P';

my_stored_proc(
    h_id => h_id,
    h_type => h_type,
    h_reason => h_reason,
    h_position => h_position
  );
END;
```

The stored procedure does insert a right set of values, so it is not the stored procedure that is at fault. Do I need to specify all the parameters even if not all are utilized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, I have had numerous issues with `MapSqlParameterSource` and ever since, I have switched to using `Map<String, Object>` to resolve the issue of variable binding.